# Cant change date range for loading data via js dev tools

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, get, picker

There is web page with exchange historical data: https://www.investing.com/indices/volatility-s-p-500-historical-data

Page contains dates-filter (range) and apply button (need to click on dates-range):
[<img1>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyYRs.png)

If I change date field via html picker and press "Apply" button - historical data updates perfectly.
[<img2>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAVRd.png)

But i want to update the page via Selenium webdriver. So the main thing I want to archive for now - update the page in Chrome dev tools, get old data.

What I try:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyYRs.png) I open small modal with 2 dates via click after page load:
`document.getElementsByClassName("flex flex-1 flex-col justify-center text-sm leading-5 text-[#333]")[0].nextSibling.click()`
and see 2 date fields and "Apply" button.

[2] I set the input field value to new value (2022-01-01):
`document.getElementsByClassName("absolute left-0 top-0 h-full w-full opacity-0")[0].value="2022-01-01";`
[<img3>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVIhF.png)

[3] I "click" the apply button:
`document.getElementsByClassName("flex cursor-pointer items-center gap-3 rounded bg-v2-blue py-2.5 pl-4 pr-6 shadow-button")[0].click();`

[4] .... GET request from page contains old data range so data does't update, but input field value is updated in [2])!
[<img4>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xxihC.png)

Whats wrong?

As I understand:

- There is 2 input fields id DOM ("from date" and "till date"):
  `<input class="absolute left-0 top-0 h-full w-full opacity-0" type="date" max="2024-03-29" value="2024-02-29">`
- If we change that fileds values from html picker (.showPicker) - all works fine.
- If we change that fields values from Chrome dev tools (.value = "new date", see [2] above) - dont work.

So I can guess, that there is event, that fires only from html picker click. And that event stores in some place valid date-range (stored date-range is using in GET-request to background api).

[I looked throught descr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) - no ideas :(

I checked cookies  (I thought that date-range is stored here by hidden picker eventhandle) - no results. I checked "Event Listeners" tab in Chrome dev tools - no results (maybe I was looking in the wrong place/event or didnt understand info).

How can I set dates range from Chrome Dev Tools and receive historical data?
Thank you and sorry, the great Web is not really my thing, I'm a C# backend developer :)
All I need - get data to local DB via Selenium for some research.